# Good Place for File/Backup Dedicated Server?

Tags: web-hosting, server, backups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for a cheap dedicated server for file hosting / backup only. Basically I just want something with minimal CPU & RAM, but with maximum arrays of hard drives (e.g. 4x 4TB hard drives per server, RAID 10).

Anyone know of a good dedicated server provider that can offer this type of deal?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. I am not inexperienced, I am asking for a recommendation. Please reopen my question or inform me which rule I have broken.

Comment: At the top of that question is a link to [the meta discussion](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/584/we-need-to-decide-what-were-doing-with-web-hosting-questions) where it is explained why all hosting request questions are closed as duplicates of that question.